# Load cms block based on attribute text

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

I have a custom tab on the product page which at the moment shows a static block.

What I need it to do is to show a different static block based on the text of an attribute.

For example, the tab will show a phtml file checking the text of a custom attribute then displaying the correct static block.

Comment: Your custom attribute type is drop-down or text?

Comment: Drop down but can be changed if needed

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code you could share with us or a certain specific issue you run into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As per your requirement you will need to create number of static blocks same as your drop-down values.**

Now for example you have drop-down attribute values `test1,test2,test3` etc...

Create your static blocks with identifier `static_blick_test1, static_blick_test2, static_blick_test3` etc...

Now in your phtml file you must have current product object and you can call it like.

```
<?php $attributeValue = strtolower($product->getAttributeText('custom_attribute_code')); ?>
```

Now based on this attribute value create your static block identifier like

```
<?php $staticBlockIdentifier = "static_block_".$attributeValue; ?>
```

Now you can call this static block like

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("cms/block")->setBlockId($staticBlockIdentifier)->toHtml();?>
```

**This way you can call your static block dynamically as per your custom attribute value in your product tab.**

Comment: So I put all 3 in the phtml file? What do you mean current product object? Sorry :s

Comment: $product = Mage::registry('çurrent_product'); or your file should have block 'catalog/product_view'

Comment: You helped a lot, thank you. you have a typo though it should be $product = Mage::registry('current_product');